# How do I display an image next to input field on the same line in the view?

Tags: cakephp

I have a question about how to display a input field and an image in one line (View).

Try to set up a view for a ajax input field.

```
echo $this->Form->input('Rabatt Code', array('id' => 'discountcode'));
```

Now, I want to display a processing image next (!) to the input field.

```
echo $this->Html->image('ajax/loader.gif');
```

The image gets an own input div around it, and breaks to a new line.

I found a few solutions how to arrange the label of an input field, but none for a 'new' input field.

Comment: I would not recommend such a field name. Try to stick to conventions - `input('discount_code')` - english and lowercase underscored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to disable the div surrounding the label and the input :

```
echo $this->Form->input('Rabatt Code', array('div' => false, 'id' => 'discountCode')); ?>
```

And add another div arround input and image ;)